# There is a plane given the equation. If a sphere is tangent to this plane, what is the equation for the sphere?(Sphere Center: ${M(4,-2.3)}$)

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry, spheres

This is **plane equation**:
${-2x+y-2z+7=0}$

What is the equation for the sphere tangent to this plane? **Center of the sphere = ${M(4,-2,3)}$**

Sphere equation form:
${(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}=r^{2}}$

If center values are placed in place:
${(x-4)^{2}+(y+2)^{2}+(z-3)^{2}=r^{2}}$

So,
Since the sphere is tangent to the plane, they intersect at a common point, and this intersection ${P(x,y,z)}$ point must satisfy both the plane equation and the sphere equation, right?
I request your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of the normal vector $(-2, 1, 2)$ is $3$. Hence the radius of the sphere is
\begin{equation}
r = |-2(4)+(-2)-2(3)+7|/3 = 9/3=3
\end{equation}
The point where they cross is $(4, -2, 3) \pm (-2, 1, -2)r/3 = (2, -1, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks. So is there a way to find the point where they cross?

Comment: For clarification, the point where they cross is the intersection of the plane and the line perpendicular to the plane passing through the point, because that is the point of the plane that is closest to $M$.

Comment: Ok. Many thanks.